# JSON via NodeJS Express Websocket has lots extra characters

Tags: node.js, json, express

I have a nodeJS server configured with Express and BodyParser

```
const express = require('express')
const expressWs = require('express-ws')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.ws('/ws', websocket)
```

When the websocket gets a message I pass it on

```
ws.onmessage = e => {
    const {action, payload} = JSON.parse(e.data)
    channel.send(action,payload)
}
```

However when it comes to the app via the channel it's got lots of extra characters in it

```
"{\"action\":\"guide_data_retreived\",\"payload\":[{\"id\":544,\"json\":\"{\\\"code\\\":\\\"lPvwP4rz\\\",\\\"coverDesign\\\":null,\\\"created\\\":1535018423000,\\\"description\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"blocks\\\\\\\":[{\\\\\\\"key\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"dpcth\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"text\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"This is an example of a medical emergency. \\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"type\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"unstyled\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\"depth\\\\\\\":0,\\\\\\\"inlineStyleRanges\\\\\\\":[],\\\\\\\"entityRanges\\\\\\\":[],\\\\\\\"data\\\\\\\":{}},
```

Which makes it unparseable.

Any idea where this is coming from and how to fix it?

Comment: why don't you use JSON.stringify to send it out?

Comment: The problem here is too much stringify and not enough parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have several levels of string-encoded JSON nested within your objects.

The `\`'s are escape characters.  They are there to indicate that the quote following them is not a terminating quote, but rather is a character in the string.  So for instance, let's say I want to have a javascript object which looks like this:

```
// myFile.javascript
{ "x" : "abc" }
const s = JSON.stringify(foo) // s is a string
```

Then `s` will include these escape characters, so that the quotes around `"x"` and `"abc"` will be interpreted as *inside* the string rather than as string terminators:

```
s == "{\"x\":\"abc\"}" // -> true
```

So since `s` is a string, you can also put it inside another object, like this:

```
const bar = { "nested" : s }
```

And if you stringify that, you will end up with *another* level of escapes to signify that `s` is a string and not a nested JSON object within the object:

```
JSON.stringify(bar) == "{\"nested\":\"{\\"x\\":\\"abc\\"}\"}
```

So it's clear that within your application, you're passing around strings instead of objects.  For instance, inside your `payload`, `json` is a nested string-encoaded JSON, and inside `json`, `description` is string-encoaded-JSON.

If you have control over the message being sent on this websocket, then you should parse those strings before you put them in the payload.

So for instance, if you are building the payload like this:

```
func sendMessage(ws, action, id, json) {
  ws.send(action, {id: id, json: json})
}
```

then you should change it to this:

```
func sendMessage(ws, action, id, json) {
  ws.send(action, {id: id, json: JSON.parse(json)})
}
```

And so on, for each level of nested object.